# How to interpret memory map dump output?

Tags: debugging, gcc

my question is not relative to the error itself (I know what is the reason for it).

I would instead like to know how to read this dump (meaning of the fields, flags and so on), where it is produced (glibc, or gcc libraries) and how I can infer what's wrong from it at a higher level (e.g. some tool that might find this output useful).

```
*** glibc detected *** python: double free or corruption (fasttop): 0x0000000006c4eb90 ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x7eb96)[0x7f6c3a0a1b96]
/usr/lib/nvidia-current-updates/tls/libnvidia-tls.so.304.88(+0x1cc1)[0x7f6c2e544cc1]
======= Memory map: ========
00400000-00401000 r-xp 00000000 08:07 2238049                          /build/bin/python
00600000-00601000 r--p 00000000 08:07 2238049                          /build/bin/python
00601000-00602000 rw-p 00001000 08:07 2238049                          /build/bin/python
00954000-07625000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                                  [heap]
40c14000-40c92000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f6c04000000-7f6c041bc000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f6c041bc000-7f6c08000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f6c08000000-7f6c081bc000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f6c081bc000-7f6c0c000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f6c0c000000-7f6c0c1bc000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f6c0c1bc000-7f6c10000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f6c14000000-7f6c14021000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f6c14021000-7f6c18000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f6c1ab5a000-7f6c1ab5b000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f6c1ab5b000-7f6c1af5b000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
7f6c1af5b000-7f6c1af5c000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f6c1af5c000-7f6c1b35c000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
7f6c1b35c000-7f6c1b35d000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f6c1b35d000-7f6c1b75d000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
7f6c1b75d000-7f6c1b767000 r-xp 00000000 08:05 1314563                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_nis-2.15.so
7f6c1b767000-7f6c1b967000 ---p 0000a000 08:05 1314563                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_nis-2.15.so
7f6c1b967000-7f6c1b968000 r--p 0000a000 08:05 1314563                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_nis-2.15.so
7f6c1b968000-7f6c1b969000 rw-p 0000b000 08:05 1314563                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_nis-2.15.so
7f6c1b969000-7f6c1b980000 r-xp 00000000 08:05 1314576                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnsl-2.15.so
```

Comment: It is produced by inspecting the /proc filesystem ( /proc/map ?) for the given process. You could do that from the command line, too. (I think it is `cat /proc{pid}/smaps` )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The man page for proc has the answer.  The memory map output format is given in the entry for /proc/[pid]/maps.

The short summary is going across the columns it is: memory range, permissions, offset, device (major:minor), inode, and pathname.